# Calling NSURL Initializer without specifying the argument name

Tags: swift

I have the following implementation:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com") WORKS

let url1 = NSURL("http://www.google.com") DOES NOT WORK
```

The first one works and the second one does not. It seems that it requires the named parameter "string". Why is that?

Comment: Per https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html - External parameter names must always be used in an initializer if they are defined, and omitting them is a compile-time error.

Comment: It's by design to avoid ambiguity, since there are other methods that take a single parameter to create an NSURL object.